# Local storage - WInJS - Windows Universal 8.1 App

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-store-apps, local-storage

I have points for plotting in an multi-dimensional array. I am doing windows universal app with local storage to store contents of it in the file where users create it.

The problem is i cant able to store and retrieve properly from local storage of winjs.

My Array structure:

```
arr[0] = new ptt("A", new Array(
         new Point(30, 7, 1), new Point(103, 7, 1),
         new Point(66, 7, 2), new Point(66, 87, 2)
     ));
```

What i tried is i just wrap everything in

```
JSON.Stringify(arr);
```

And write it on file in local storage / roaming storage of app and for retrieval:

```
JSON.Parse(content_of_file);
```

but i cannot able to store or create and cannot check if file already exist. help me.

Comment: are you wanting this written to a file or to localStorage?

Comment: @J.Wells as size is huge i want to write in file on local folder of app

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747550/metro-style-app-html-js-writing-local-files) help?

Comment: @J.Wells You saved me man !!! thank you :) #Worked like charm